# Can we solve an algebraic system where the number of equations is less than the number of unknowns?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is it necessary to always have the number of equations >= number of unknown variables to solve the problem? Can we have the question where this is not true?

Comment: How many solutions are there for the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ in the reals?

Comment: When you say "to solve the problem" do you mean that the system has a unique solution?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, no.

Consider $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

The fact that we have but one equation doesn't mean we can't solve the problem.
It only means there is more than one solution (in this case $x = cos(t), y = sin(t)$ is an infinite amount of solutions).

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by solve. You can describe the solution set of the system of (linear) equations regardless of how many there are, but they may not determine a unique solution. To get a single solution you must have at least as many equations as variables. Think about determining a point in the plane with lines, you need at least two. Similarly in $\mathbb{R}^3$, three planes are needed.

Comment: You don't necessarily need more equations than variables if the some of the equations eliminate impossible solutions.  $x^2 + x^2 = 0$ x, y real has only 1 solution.  This is sort of cheating as we are using information more than what is provided in by just the equation.

Comment: Good point. I should have put the 'linear' disclaimer in more places.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the problem "the number of equations >= number of unknown variables" in linear system of equations. The answer is **The Kronecker-Capelli** for linear system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ be a polynomial function. Thus $f(X)=0$ is a system of $n$ algebraic equations in $m$ unknowns. If $n<m$, then $\{X;f(X)=0\}$ is void or has an infinity of elements. The proof is very easy when we consider affine equations. It is much more difficult in the general case, cf. my post in:

[How to prove rigorously that you need $m \geq n$ equations with $n$ unknowns to be able to solve a system of equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356202/how-to-prove-rigorously-that-you-need-m-geq-n-equations-with-n-unknowns-to/1359365#1359365)